# Is there a recommended frequency when driving an alkaline water electrolyzer?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

We are designing a small electrolyzer (about 1 kW input power) for [HHO gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen) generation.
Sadly most of the literature online is bordering on the snake oil… However, it works fine with DC driving. Now from the electrical side the cell is a quite complex model (the current–voltage curve depends on anything under the sun) and we want to give a way to regulate the amount of gas produced. The idea would be some kind of [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation).

I found an article by Mazloomi et al. [1] (there are some thing inside I'm not very convinced of, first of all the circuit model) but the current transient matches what we see:

- An initial peak (the electrolyzer plates charging as capacitor?)
- An exponential rise (the actual electrochemistry starting up?)

My guess it that the *minimum* frequency for a PWM drive would be such that at least the current transient completes. But I also read that the gas formation processes are somewhat slow, due to bubble mechanics.

The question is: is there a recommended frequency for driving such an electrolyzer cell? I am thinking about three possible outcomes:

- Ultra low frequency, like turning on 10 s the generator and let it idle 2s;
- Low frequency, around 100 to 1000 Hz, where the transient completes (electrically) but I don't have a reasonably good idea of what's happening on the chemistry side;
- High frequency (kHz range) where the electrical inductance in practice becomes a (lower) constant current and the generator is substantially at a DC steady state.

The first way is easy to do but the discontinuity in generation is problematic; the third way gives substantial thermal stress on the electronics due to switching losses. The middle way seems a good compromise to me. Are there some guidelines? Any kind of pointer can be useful.

#### Reference

1. Mazloomi, K.; Sulaiman, N.; Ahmad, S.; Md Yunus, N. Analysis of the Frequency Response of a Water Electrolysis Cell. *Int. J. Electrochem. Sci* **2013**, 8. ([PDF](http://www.electrochemsci.org/papers/vol8/80303731.pdf))

Comment: Why do you want to produce electrolysis with pulses ? is there any advantage ?

Comment: it's for controlling the amount of gas produced, the supply is not completely controlled and the application call for different flow rates

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand a word of your explanation.

Comment: It's brown gas, just electrolyze water and mix the outputs. Huge safety concerns for the obvious reasons. Anyway it seems there is not much around so I guess it's time for practical tests!

Comment: What ? A brown gas ? Which brown gas ? $\ce{NO2}$  ? What are you doing ? What is the composition of the solution to be electrolyzed ? I thought you wanted to produce hydrogen and oxygen !

Comment: @Maurice Not "brown gas", but "Brown's gas" aka [Oxyhydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen)